# How does one indicate exemption from travel restrictions for an Australian Visitor Visa (600)?

Tags: visas, covid-19, australia

My wife is applying for an Australian [Tourist-stream Visitor Visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas).  The website indicates that

> We are prioritising visa applications for travellers who are exempt from our travel restrictions.

How can she demonstrate that she is exempt from the Covid-related travel restrictions due to being the spouse of an Australian citizen, given that the application appears not to ask about my nationality, nor does it include an "any other information" field that can be used to provide relevant information for which there was no specific field?

Comment: Which form is she using? There should be questions regarding purpose of stay ("Purpose of stay", "Why do you want to visit Australia?", in addition to questions for family information ("Will the applicant visit any relatives, friends or contacts while in Australia?", "Family [NOT] travelling to Australia with you", "Do you have any relatives in Australia? [Are they] Citizen or permanent
resident of Australia[?]").

Comment: Shoehorning it into the purpose makes sense.  Because we live outside Australia I am not in the "relatives in Australia" response, and the other forms don't ask about my citizenship so it can't be provided there.

Comment: The situation is unusual enough that it might be worth it to call or email the Australian embassy in your country, if possible, to ask for advice.

Comment: You can apply for an exemption [after you have applied for a visa](https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/travel-restrictions#toc-7). Presumably they will process the visa after they have granted the exemption

Comment: @molypot: In this case she is an exempt person so the individual exemption process doesn't apply. We also can only apply for the exemption within two months of travel, anyway. What we eventually settled on was to mention my citizenship in as many places as possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.